# Intellij plugin to filter logs?

Tags: user-interface, logging, intellij-idea

Some time ago when android development was done on eclipse i remember that ADB viewer (or whatever its called) allowed you to filter and see only say DEBUG logs then you could just change it from drop down menu and you'd have all logs of specified level (also all logs were colored).

Now on Intellij i found a good plugin called grep console which allows to color your log output using regex, however i couldn't find anything that could actually filter the output in the console window to the level you want to...

**Is there any solution for this?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The plugin offers "filter out" option which hides matching lines.
You can setup expressions for various log levels and control which ones to filter out.
Or you can try to specify expression which matches any input but with needed level and filter it out.

As a last resort, the plugin is open source, so you can add any needed feature. But I believe it's not necessary.

BTW, nice plugin, thank you.

Comment: Oh i guess i started using it a while ago, configured colors and didn't see that feature added later :)

Answer (score 2):

If the console is in focus you can ctrl-f which will bring up find options. Then you can type in whatever you are interested in. Unfortunately you have to do this every time. Its easier than fiddling about with grep console which is a separate window.